# Geometric Interpretation of members of $\mathrm{O}(2)\setminus\mathrm{SO}(2)$

Tags: group-theory, matrices

I recently came across a question which asked to prove the defining properties of the orthogonal matrices (members of $\mathrm{O}(2)$), then to subsequently determine that they can be written in the form:

$$\mathbf{R}(\varphi)=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\varphi) & \mp \sin(\varphi) \\ \sin(\varphi) & \pm \cos(\varphi)\end{pmatrix}$$

It then asks us which of these matrices correspond to two-dimensional rotations (i.e. members of the group $\mathrm{SO}(2)$). However, my question is as follows:

> What is the geometrical interpretation of matrices $M\in\mathrm{O}(2)\setminus \mathrm{SO}(2)$?

My gut feeling is that these matrices somehow invert the points that they rotate, because $\det(M)=-1$, however, I am not sure if this is true and would like clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrices in $O(2) \setminus SO(2)$ are exactly those that can be written as $FR$, where $R$ is a rotation, and $F$ is the diagonal matrix with $-1, 1$ as diagonal entries, i.e., a flip around the y-axis. So every matrix in your class is just a rotation followed by an orientation-reversal, or "flip", or whatever you like.

(Proof of my claim: suppose $M$ is in $O(2)\setminus SO(2)$. Then $FM$ is in $SO(2)$ because it has determinant $+1$. Hence it's a rotation $R$. Since $FM = R$, and $FF = I$, we have $M = FFM = FR$. )

Answer (score 2):

They are reflections around a line.